# Yii2 upload file not getting uploaded to folder

Tags: php, yii2

Hi im trying to upload an image but the image is not getting uploaded to the folder.
and i don´t get any error message is there anyone that have a solution to this i followed the documentation on https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload
Controller

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new UploadForm();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->imageFile = Uploadedfile::getInstance($model, 'imagefile');
        
        if ($model->upload()) {
            return;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

Model

```
public $imageFile;
public $hight;
public $width;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, gif'],
    ];
}

public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        
        $path = $this->uploadPath() . $this->imageFile->namespace . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension;
        $this->imageFile->saveAs($path);
        $this->image = $this->imageFile->basename . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function uploadPath(){
    return 'basic/web/uploads/';
}
```

View

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>
            

            <button>Resize</button>
            <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think file was not saved to basic/web/uploads folder, please do according to ex, $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' ...

Also try create folder 'uploads' in web/, after this check permissions to the folder

Comment: i tryed but did not work but how do i check permissions on the folder

Comment: cd projectFolder && sudo chmod 777 -R web/uploads

Comment: okay i´ll try. thank you for your help might but it away for a bit. but again thank you